# Axios GET database interrogation

Tags: axios

I am using `axios` to interogate my database.
In one instance, I am using `post` to a route with this format(with parameters): `/cards/modify` to `INSERT` data into the database, and it works just fine, but if i want tot `GET` the row count from a `table` on the router `/cards/count`, the `node` server does not respond back with the results, but if I'm changing it to only `/count`, it works just fine.
My question is does `POST` work, but `GET` doesn't on the same format of `route`?
Thanks.

EDIT:

```
router.post('/cards/modify', (request, response) => {
    let query = database.query('UPDATE cards SET laneID = ? where ID = ?', [request.body.lane, request.body.id], (error, result, fields) => {
        if(error){
            console.log('Database error: ' + error);
            return;
        }
    });
    //send a response
    // console.log(request.body);
});

router.get('/count', (request, response) => {
    let query = database.query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM cards', (error, result, fields) => {
        if(error){
            console.log('Databse error at users: ' + error);
            return;
        }
        response.send(result);
    });
});

app.use(router);
```

Comment: Based on what you've mentioned, there's no conclusion that can be drawn here. In general, web servers can have endpoints (urls) which only respond to `POST`, and others which only respond to `GET` (or both).  How are your routes set up?

Comment: I've added some code. These work, but if I switch the `/count' to '/cards/count`, it does not work anymore.